# NavigationExperimental: Pop of scene cause rerender of popped scene

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use NavigationExperimental from React-Native with Redux. If I stand in Scene A and push Scene B everything is great. However if press the backbutton in the header and pop Scene B and return to Scene A, then Scene A gets rendered first, then Scene B, then Scene A. I check this by adding a `console.log()` in the `render` method. Is this normal behavior in React-Native or is my implementation wrong?

Heres scene A:

```
class Home extends Component {

render() {

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
           <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onPress}>
            <Text>Go to about</Text>
           </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Heres scene B:

```
class About extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text>Hello from About</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default About;
```

And here is the class that handles navigation:

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._renderHeader = this._renderHeader.bind(this);
    this._renderScene = this._renderScene.bind(this);
    this._navigatePush = this._navigatePush.bind(this);
    this._navigatePop = this._navigatePop.bind(this);
    this._renderHeader = this._renderHeader.bind(this);
    this._renderTitle = this._renderTitle.bind(this);
}

render() {
    return (
        <NavigationCardStack
            navigationState={this.props.navigation}
            onNavigate={this._navigatePush}
            renderScene={this._renderScene}
            renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
            />
    )
}

_renderHeader(props) {
        return <NavigationHeader {...props} renderTitleComponent={this._renderTitle} onNavigateBack={this._navigatePop} />
}

_renderTitle(props) {
    return <NavigationHeader.Title>{props.scene.route.title}</NavigationHeader.Title>
}

_renderScene(props) {
    const key = props.scene.route.key;

    switch (key) {
        case 'Home':
            return <Home onPress={() => this._navigatePush({ key: 'About', title: 'About' })} />
        case 'About':
            return <About />
    }
}

_navigatePush(scene) {
    this.props.navigationActions.pushRoute(scene);
}

_navigatePop() {
    this.props.navigationActions.popRoute()
}
```

Edit: Added my navigationReducer and navigationActions:

```
//action creators
function _pushRoute(route) {
return {
    type: actionTypes.PUSH,
    route
}

function _popRoute() {
return {
    type: actionTypes.POP,
}

//thunks
export function pushRoute(route){
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(_pushRoute(route))
}

export function popRoute(route){
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(_popRoute())
}

//Reducer

initialState = {
index: 0,
key: 'root',
routes: [
    { key: 'Home', title: 'Home' }
]
}

function navReducer() {
return (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.PUSH:
            if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
            return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route);
        case actionTypes.POP:
            if (state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1) return state
            return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state)
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do your `navigationActions.pushRoute(scene);
 ` and `navigationActions.popRoute() methods look`

Comment: Added those in my answer @NaderDabit.

Comment: Maybe try removing the `onNavigate={this._navigatePush}` ?

Comment: That doesn't change anything. I see now that onNavigate maybe is not necessary based on how I implemented everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's ok, That's a known NavigationExperimental issue.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/c8a7f9e2d1618b5feea68915b5e2e4f12247ceed/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationCardStack.js#L258

Here is the line which will call the render in your every scene every time when you push/pop or do something else.

But you can build you own navigation stack, using `<NavigationTransitioner />`

But doing it please refer this issue.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10835 .

If you don't know how to build your own navigation, you can see NavigationCardStack file and see what
 they did there.